# Zustand object functions not setting state / not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, zustand

I am very new to react. I came across zustand for state management but it apparently isn't working in my application

I basically cant update state of any object / variable

Here is the code with zustand

Store.jsx

```
import create from 'zustand'

const useStoreZu = create(set => ({
  bears: 0,
  increasePopulation: () => set(state => ({ bears: state.bears + 1 })),
  removeAllBears: () => set({ bears: 0 })
}))

export default useStoreZu
```

```
const handleCallbackResponse = async (res) => {
        // Dispatch Login Init
        dispatchLogin({
            type: "LOGIN_INIT"
        })

        const userObj = jwt_decode(res.credential);

        try {
            const server_session_token = await axios({
                method: 'post',
                url: `${API_ENDPOINT}/login`,
                data: {
                    email: userObj.email
                }
            })

            console.log(bears);

            increasePopulation(1);
            increasePopulation(1);
            increasePopulation(1);
            increasePopulation(1);
            increasePopulation(1);
            increasePopulation(1);

            console.log(bears);

            // Direct Login
            dispatchLogin({
                type: "DIRECT_LOGIN",
                payload: server_session_token
            })
            
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
```

even after calling increasePopulation the bears variable isn't being updated. This is the same any variable / object.

I used the boilerplate code from the website directly for debugging but I am basically trying to store the user information I get from hitting the api

I tried searching for solution but couldn't find anywhere.

Comment: State changes are async and your constant will reflect the updated value on the next render.